# Trying to create dashboard using SharePoint BI Center. Having troubles using SharePoint list as a data source due to Unattended Service Account

Tags: sharepoint-designer, dashboard, bi

I am having trouble trying to create a valid Unattended Service Account in order to have a SharePoint list become a data source for my Dashboard Designer.

I have set the Unattended Service Account to my SharePoint account, Nav.Bowman, and went back to the Dashboard Designer and select Unattended Serivce Account as my Authentication means, I still get errors:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unattended Service Account is an Active Directory account that is used for accessing PerformancePoint Services data sources. This account is used by PerformancePoint Services on behalf of authorized users to provide access to external data sources for the purposes of creating and using dashboards and other PerformancePoint Services content.

1. Make sure Unattended Service Account configured properly
2. For SQL Server data, the account must have a SQL logon with db_datareader permissions on each database that you want to access.
3. For SQL Server Analysis Services data, the account must have read access to the cube or an appropriate portion of the cube, depending on your needs.
4. For Excel Services data, the account must have access to the Microsoft Excel workbook in a SharePoint document library.
5. For data in a SharePoint list, the account must have read access to the list.

Refer this [site](http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2013/09/04/troubleshooting-performancepoint-dashboard-designer-data-connectivity-to-sharepoint-lists/)